# SpriteKit: Cloning Nodes

Tags: sprite-kit, cloning, swift2

So I would like to make a block of code that will run inside the sprite node every frame. The result would be me tapping and creating a bubble there that would then float up using sine. Is that possible to code into the bubble? Sorry if this seems vague, I'm just not sure what to call it. The closest thing I can think of it cloning and each clone runs the same script every frame. Anyways, Here's what I have now.

```
let bubble = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"bubble")    
bubble.position.x = CGFloat(rand())*self.frame.width
bubble.position.y = -20

//Code for bubble to run each frame

self.addChild(bubble)
```

Comment: So do you want each bubble to move a certain amount every some amount of seconds, or you want the bubbles to move based on their position every some amount of seconds?

Comment: I'd like them to not only accelerate moving up, but also oscillate going left and right using sine. I don't want to use any SKActions. I'd really like to just be able to code them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what you are looking for is `enumerateChildNodesWithName`. When it is called, it will run the code it contains on every node with the name you put in it.

```
bubble.name = "bubble"
```

If you name bubble "bubble", all of its child nodes will also be named "bubble".

```
enumerateChildNodesWithName("bubble"){node, stop in
        let bubbleChild:SKSpriteNode = node as! SKSpriteNode

        //Run the code telling them what to do here. You should make it so that
        //it can figure out how to move the node a slight amount based on its position
}
```

You could call this by putting it in a function that is called by a timer, and the timer should be called frequently, like every `0.017` seconds (Approximately 60 times a second) so that the motion is smooth. For example:

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(NSTimeInterval(0.017), target: self, selector: Selector("moveBubbles:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Then, to make a function that the timer calls:

```
func moveBubbles(timer: NSTimer!){
    //enumerateChildNodesWithName here
}
```

There is more information on `enumerateChildNodesWithName` [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/enumerateChildNodesWithName:usingBlock:), and more information on `NSTimer` [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/).

Comment: I could replace the timer with the loop I already have, right?

Comment: Yeah. You just need it to loop in some way.

Comment: Okay so I got that working but now how do I add multiple children of an SKSprite node into a view? If I try to add 2 it gives me a SIGBART error.

Comment: Okay I ended up using a for loop that defined the sprite every time instead of defining it out of the loop. Hopefully that will work out. Thank you so much for all your help I really appreciate it!